# Are these sets open or closed in the topology of compact convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We look at the continuous functions $[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is a continuous funciton, $\epsilon>0$, I am wondering if the set $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in [0,\infty)\}$ is open and if the set $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon, \forall x \in [0,\infty)\}$ is closed?

**attempt:**

If we first look at the set $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x \in [0,\infty)\}$ and if $h$ is in the set. Then if it was open there must be a basis element that contains $h$ and is in the set. A basis element is of the set $B_{\epsilon_2,C,v}=\{g: |g(x)-v(x)|<\epsilon_2,\forall x \in C \}$, where $C$ is a compact set, and $v$ is a continuous funciton. It does seem intuitive that this set can not be contained in the original set because we only have control on what happens on a compact set, but how do we hammer down the argument precisely?

If we look at the set $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon,\forall x \in [0,\infty)\}$ this set contains a condition on what happens on the entire real line, but the basis elements are only on compact sets. However this set is the intersection of the sets $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon, \forall x \in [0,n]\}$ and since an infinite intersection of closed sets is closed the result will follow if $\{g: g \in C([0,\infty)), |g(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon, \forall x \in [0,n]\}$ is closed? Can we say that this last set is closed?

Comment: The first one (let's call it $A$) isn't open, to prove this we need to find a sequence $f_n$ in the complement of $A$ such that the limit lies in $A$. Let $f(x)=0$ and take any $\varepsilon$, the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}x$ is contained in the compliment of $A$ but converges to $0$ in compacts. So that set is not open.

Comment: The second one is closed, and your way to prove it is correct, but to see it even easier, convergence in compacts implies pointwise convergence, and if $|g_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon$ then $\lim_n|g_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon$, since $g_n\to\lim_n g_n(x)$ in compacts, this prooves that your set is closed.

Comment: @MatíasUres Thank you very much!